# Exception in Generating EMF model code in XText Eclipse DSL Tools Version: 2019-03 RC1 (4.11 RC1) - Windows 10

Tags: xtext

I consistently get exception while running maven package goal -- I selected the following options in the project wizard

Accepted default project name and language name on first page, 
 - Java Execution environment 1.8 (jdk1.8.0_151),

and on the second page:
 - Eclipse Plugin
 - Web Integration
 - Testing Support JUnit 5
 - Preferred Build System -- Maven
 - Build Language Server -- Fat Jar
 - Source Layout -- Plain

Once the projects are created, from the parent project I select Run As->Maven Build and supply "clean package" in goals. "clean" succeeds but the build fails with following exception trace.  I did remember to set the active target platform. Something to note, Gradle build works but my use case requires creating language server as well as eclispe plugin. I have tried Gradle with addtinal tycho maven build but without success. It maven build fails the same way.Please let me know if I am doing something incorrectly.

---

```
2054 [org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main()] INFO  text.xtext.generator.XtextGenerator  - Generating org.xtext.example.mydsl1.MyDsl
4186 [org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main()] INFO  nerator.ecore.EMFGeneratorFragment2  - Generating EMF model code
Mar 12, 2019 12:50:30 PM org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils.GenModelHelper registerGenModel
INFO: Registered GenModel 'http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl1/MyDsl' from 'platform:/resource/org.xtext.example.mydsl1/model/generated/MyDsl.genmodel'
org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException: org.eclipse.emf.codegen.jet.JETException: InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.AbstractGeneratorAdapter.generateJava(AbstractGeneratorAdapter.java:2108)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.generator.GenPackageGeneratorAdapter.generatePackageInterface(GenPackageGeneratorAdapter.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.generator.GenPackageGeneratorAdapter.generateModel(GenPackageGeneratorAdapter.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.generator.GenBaseGeneratorAdapter.doGenerate(GenBaseGeneratorAdapter.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.AbstractGeneratorAdapter.generate(AbstractGeneratorAdapter.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.ecore.EMFGeneratorFragment2.doGenerate(EMFGeneratorFragment2.java:1015)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.ecore.EMFGeneratorFragment2.generate(EMFGeneratorFragment2.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.CompositeGeneratorFragment2.generate(CompositeGeneratorFragment2.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.XtextGenerator.invokeInternal(XtextGenerator.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.Mwe2Bridge.invoke(Mwe2Bridge.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.Workflow.run(Workflow.java:20)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.run(Mwe2Launcher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main(Mwe2Launcher.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.eclipse.emf.codegen.jet.JETException: InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.jet.JETEmitter.generate(JETEmitter.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.AbstractGeneratorAdapter.generateJava(AbstractGeneratorAdapter.java:1979)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.jet.JETEmitter.generate(JETEmitter.java:459)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.emf.codegen.util.CodeGenUtil.xmlEscapeEncode(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.impl.GenBaseImpl.appendModelSetting(GenBaseImpl.java:1925)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.impl.GenPackageImpl.getModelInfo(GenPackageImpl.java:4240)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.templates.model.PackageClass.generate(PackageClass.java:424)
    ... 32 more
org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException: org.eclipse.emf.codegen.jet.JETException: InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.AbstractGeneratorAdapter.generateJava(AbstractGe4648 [org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main()] WARN  nerator.ecore.EMFGeneratorFragment2  - Diagnostic ERROR source=org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore code=0 Generating code data=[] [Diagnostic OK source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 OK data=[], Diagnostic OK source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 OK data=[], Diagnostic OK source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 OK data=[], Diagnostic OK source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 OK data=[], Diagnostic OK source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 OK data=[], Diagnostic ERROR source=org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore code=0 Generating Java interface org.xtext.example.mydsl1.myDsl.MyDslPackage failed with an unhandled exception data=[] [Diagnostic ERROR source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 InvocationTargetException data=[java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException] [Diagnostic ERROR source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.emf.codegen.util.CodeGenUtil.xmlEscapeEncode(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; data=[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.emf.codegen.util.CodeGenUtil.xmlEscapeEncode(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;]]], Diagnostic ERROR source=org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore code=0 Generating Java interface org.xtext.example.mydsl1.myDsl.Model failed with an unhandled exception data=[] [Diagnostic ERROR source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 InvocationTargetException data=[java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException] [Diagnostic ERROR source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.emf.codegen.util.CodeGenUtil.xmlEscapeEncode(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; data=[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.emf.codegen.util.CodeGenUtil.xmlEscapeEncode(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;]]], Diagnostic ERROR source=org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore code=0 Generating Java interface org.xtext.example.mydsl1.myDsl.Greeting failed with an unhandled exception data=[] [Diagnostic ERROR source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 InvocationTargetException data=[java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException] [Diagnostic ERROR source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.EcoreValidator$EGenericTypeBuilder.buildEGenericType(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/eclipse/emf/ecore/EGenericType; data=[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.EcoreValidator$EGenericTypeBuilder.buildEGenericType(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/eclipse/emf/ecore/EGenericType;]]], Diagnostic OK source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 OK data=[], Diagnostic OK source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 OK data=[], Diagnostic OK source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 OK data=[], Diagnostic OK source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 OK data=[]]
neratorAdapter.java:2108)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.generator.GenClassGeneratorAdapter.generateInterface(GenClassGeneratorAdapter.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.generator.GenClassGeneratorAdapter.generateModel(GenClassGeneratorAdapter.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.generator.GenBaseGeneratorAdapter.doGenerate(GenBaseGeneratorAdapter.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.AbstractGeneratorAdapter.generate(AbstractGeneratorAdapter.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.ecore.EMFGeneratorFragment2.doGenerate(EMFGeneratorFragment2.java:1015)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.ecore.EMFGeneratorFragment2.generate(EMFGeneratorFragment2.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.CompositeGeneratorFragment2.generate(CompositeGeneratorFragment2.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.XtextGenerator.invokeInternal(XtextGenerator.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.Mwe2Bridge.invoke(Mwe2Bridge.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.Workflow.run(Workflow.java:20)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.run(Mwe2Launcher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main(Mwe2Launcher.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.eclipse.emf.codegen.jet.JETException: InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.jet.JETEmitter.generate(JETEmitter.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.AbstractGeneratorAdapter.generateJava(AbstractGeneratorAdapter.java:1979)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.jet.JETEmitter.generate(JETEmitter.java:459)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.emf.codegen.util.CodeGenUtil.xmlEscapeEncode(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.impl.GenBaseImpl.appendModelSetting(GenBaseImpl.java:1917)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.impl.GenTypedElementImpl.appendModelSetting(GenTypedElementImpl.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.impl.GenFeatureImpl.getModelInfo(GenFeatureImpl.java:2315)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.impl.GenFeatureImpl.getModelInfo(GenFeatureImpl.java:2230)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.templates.model.Class$2.run(Class.java:1877)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.templates.model.Class.generate(Class.java:3908)
    ... 32 more
org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException: org.eclipse.emf.codegen.jet.JETException: InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.AbstractGeneratorAdapter.generateJava(AbstractGeneratorAdapter.java:2108)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.generator.GenClassGeneratorAdapter.generateInterface(GenClassGeneratorAdapter.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.generator.GenClassGeneratorAdapter.generateModel(GenClassGeneratorAdapter.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.generator.GenBaseGeneratorAdapter.doGenerate(GenBaseGeneratorAdapter.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.AbstractGeneratorAdapter.generate(AbstractGeneratorAdapter.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.ecore.EMFGeneratorFragment2.doGenerate(EMFGeneratorFragment2.java:1015)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.ecore.EMFGeneratorFragment2.generate(EMFGeneratorFragment2.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.CompositeGeneratorFragment2.generate(CompositeGeneratorFragment2.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.XtextGenerator.invokeInternal(XtextGenerator.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.Mwe2Bridge.invoke(Mwe2Bridge.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.Workflow.run(Workflow.java:20)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.run(Mwe2Launcher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main(Mwe2Launcher.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.eclipse.emf.codegen.jet.JETException: InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.jet.JETEmitter.generate(JETEmitter.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.AbstractGeneratorAdapter.generateJava(AbstractGeneratorAdapter.java:1979)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.jet.JETEmitter.generate(JETEmitter.java:459)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.EcoreValidator$EGenericTypeBuilder.buildEGenericType(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/eclipse/emf/ecore/EGenericType;
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.impl.GenBaseImpl.getType(GenBaseImpl.java:1344)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.impl.GenBaseImpl.getImportedType(GenBaseImpl.java:1397)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.impl.GenTypedElementImpl.getRawImportedBoundType(GenTypedElementImpl.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.templates.model.Class$2.run(Class.java:1859)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.templates.model.Class.generate(Class.java:3908)
    ... 32 more
6596 [org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main()] INFO  text.xtext.generator.XtextGenerator  - Generating common infrastructure
6637 [org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main()] INFO  .emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.Workflow  - Done.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- xtend-maven-plugin:2.17.0:compile (default) @ org.xtext.example.mydsl1 ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.eclipse.xtend.maven.XtendCompile
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/emf/common/util/WrappedException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:658)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:882)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1038)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:519)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        ... 54 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] org.xtext.example.mydsl1.parent 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT ..... SUCCESS [  0.113 s]
[INFO] org.xtext.example.mydsl1 ........................... FAILURE [  8.014 s]
[INFO] org.xtext.example.mydsl1.ide ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] org.xtext.example.mydsl1.ui ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] org.xtext.example.mydsl1.target .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] org.xtext.example.mydsl1.tests ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] org.xtext.example.mydsl1.ui.tests 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT ... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 59.088 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-12T13:04:14-07:00
```

Comment: hi i tried to reproduce this but could not. can you retry with a clean local maven repo or `mvn clean install -Dmaven.repo.local=.m2`

Comment: It worked! Thanks -- This solved so many of my problems. I really appreciate it.